# Mp3 Player Does not play file in Firefox

Tags: php, flash

The player is meant to retrieve the mp3 file from the server through the path address that is stored in MySQL. It does this in Explorer but not in Firefox. Could anyone tell me why? 
By the way the swf file of the player and the database is stored on the same server so there should be no problem with that.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="165" height="37" id="niftyPlayer1" align="">
     <param name=movie value="http:..../music/niftyplayer.swf?<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("....", "....", "....");
mysql_select_db ("....");
$query = ("select * from music where music_ID = 1");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." ".$query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo 'file=' . $row['content'] . '';

}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
&as=0">
     <param name=quality value=high>
     <param name=bgcolor value=#FFFFFF>
     <embed src="http://..../music/niftyplayer.swf?" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF width="165" height="37" name="niftyPlayer1" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
    </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because of browser security.

Try to use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ to add flash to page.

Comment: thanks but the player itself appears in both IE and FireFox its just that FF does not play the file

Answer (score 0):

```
**Issues**
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio][1]

Licensing issues: HTML5 video and H.264 – what history tells us and why we’re standing with the web and Mozilla defends Firefox's HTML5 support for only Ogg Theora video (despite their titles, they both also talk about MP3 licensing, albeit briefly).

All you can do is fall back to Flash and play them through that.
```