# Create a html5 audio and play it doesn't work

Tags: html, audio, dynamic

I want create a html5 audio in dynamic and play it,here is the code:

```
 function playAnotherMusic(playUrl){
                var audioElement = document.createElement('audio'); 
                audioElement.setAttribute('src', playUrl); 
                audioElement.setAttribute('controls', true); 
                audioElement.setAttribute('preload', true); 
                audioElement.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg'); 


                audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
                audioElement.play(); 
                }, true);

                console.log(playUrl);
                audioElement.load();

  }
```

However it doesn't work,the firebug assigin me "`HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported.`"

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the audio element to the an existing element.
This would be something like

```
document.getElementById("my_audio_div").appendChild(audioElement);
```

Idealy, this should be done before you add the event listener, but after setting all the attributes

Also try `audio/mp3` instead:
    audioElement.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mp3');

Answer (score 3):

You can't play mp3 files in firefox, it does not support them, you need an ogg version for firefox. Unless that changes, good to keep in mind.

[Why doesn't Firefox support the MP3 file format in <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)