# Is there any way that HTML Audio tag could play mp3 in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

Is there any way that `HTML` Audio tag could play `mp3` in `Firefox`.

Comment: You have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio

Comment: I know, I am looking for some way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FF currently supports only `ogg` formats, so you've to include a copy with ogg format as well:

```
<audio controls="controls"> 
    <source src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

And for sake, use old `object` tag for embedding you mp3 file as follows:

```
<object data="music.mp3" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="xxx" height="xxx">
    <param name="filename" value="music.mp3">
</object>
```

or use `embed` as:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="music.mp3" height="xxx" width="xxx" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Firefox does not support .mp3 in their audio tag. See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wait another 5 years until the remaining MP3 patents expire...

Comment: @RabNawaz Why, because it's the honest truth about the sad situation?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Boris. People should start using open formats around, as they're pretty much stable now.

Answer (score 0):

Strangly enough, firefox 3.6x and 4.x played mp3 flawless, with

```
<EMBED src="music.mp3" autostart=true loop=true volume=100 hidden=true>
```

Have two instances on my linuxbox: Firefox 4.0.1 and Firefox 20.0-> same page playes its mp3 in version 4.0.1 and does not in firefox 20.0.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking now after FF v21 (I think) mp3 and HTML 5 audio tag works

Comment: thanks for your answer, but have you tested it? A pure assumption without facts can t be an answer