# media files do not play with hidden property set to true of embed tag

Tags: html

Here is my embed tag

```
<embed src="http://localhost:8084/MIS/js/status_no.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" class="playSound">
```

When I remove hidden property, sound gets played but when i set hidden property to true, sound does not play. I do not want to show the player to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<audio>
    <source src="../js/Alarm_Buzzer.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

This worked for me in both chrome as well as firefox. Firefox did not support mp3 files but chrome did.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide it with CSS:

```
.playSound { display: none; }
```

Also I'd like to suggest using the [`audio` tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio), it's meant for this type of content.

Comment: thanks for your reply but audio tag does not seem to work on firefox. it works well on chrome though. Any suggestions for that

Comment: @sonam For FF, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675332/is-there-any-way-that-html-audio-tag-could-play-mp3-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your code into something like this and this works on all browsers

```
 <audio autoplay>
  <source src="http://localhost:8084/MIS/js/status_no.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://localhost:8084/MIS/js/status_no.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

This code will work on all browsers, it will also be hidden and will start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you add controls="controls" in audio tag then the audio player will be visible to the user.
so for your case just don't add controls.

```
<audio  src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_mfezft44rf1rge0duo1.mp3" autoplay="autoplay" loop="false" class="playSound"></audio>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=KA_8oaTpxac&autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 

wmode="transparent" height="1" width="1">
```

I think this works but note : Very important
if video on you tube : the line is :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vid number
```

but you have to write it in this form in the code

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=vid id
```

and will work fine

Comment: <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=KA_8oaTpxac&autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 

wmode="transparent" height="1" width="1">