# How to get all files from a directory and then make them into a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

For a project I'm working on now I have to manually add the functions to play songs like this

```
function song(){
    mySong.src="song1.mp3";
    mySong.play();
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Now Playing:Song1";
}
```

But I want to be able to search a directory with php, and generate those functions from php, so I don't have to manually add each song. This is my test code, I know I did it wrong but I can't seem to get it right!

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
if ($handle = opendir('/wamp/www/songs/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo 'function $entry(){mySong.src=$entry; mySong.play();       
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Now Playing:" $entry;}';
            echo "$entry";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: This one is better explained, but please indent your code.

Comment: Also, what error messages are you getting? Please [edit] your question and add those as well. Thank you.

Comment: If you use a single-quoted string (`'`), that variables inside will not be replaced with their accual values. So, use a double-quote (`"`) for the first echo.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Have the JS function defined in your page, with a parameter for the song source:</strike>

```
function song(entry){
    mySong.src=entry;
    mySong.play();
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Now Playing: " + entry;
}
```

In your PHP, you'll most likely want to echo a link to play each of the songs inside that folder, right?
Do this:

```
<?php
//Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
if ($handle = opendir('/wamp/www/songs/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="song(\'' . $entry . '\')">' . $entry . '</a><br />';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Note that this will show the file's path name with extension, for better display you'd just have to do some string manipulation with php/js `substr`/`substring` and `explode`/`split`.

Alright, I rewrote the code to work with your given example:

**JS** (head)

```
function song(entry){
    var mySong=document.getElementById("song1");
    mySong.src=entry;
    mySong.play();
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Now Playing: " + entry;
}
```

**PHP + HTML** (body)

```
<?php
//Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$path = '/wamp/www/songs/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="song(\'' . $path . $entry . '\')">' . $entry . '</a><br />';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
<p id="p2"></p>
<audio id="song1" controls="controls">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

This will work for mp3 files played in browsers with HTML5 support.

Note that Firefox doesn't support .mp3 playback inside `<audio>` tags, see: [Why doesn't Firefox support the MP3 file format in <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

Thus this solution (with your `<audio>`) will give satisfying results in Chrome only (not tested on opera and safari). You may want to fallback to another solution for more compatibility.

If you want compatibility with IE and Firefox, you can try using an `<embed>`:

**JS**

```
function song(entry){
    var mySong=document.createElement('embed');
    mySong.src=entry;
    mySong.width='250px';
    mySong.height='60px';
    document.getElementById("song1").innerHTML= '';
    document.getElementById("song1").appendChild(mySong);
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML="Now Playing: " + entry;
}
```

**PHP + HTML**

```
<?php
//Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$path = '/wamp/www/songs/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="song(\'' . $path . $entry . '\')">' . $entry . '</a><br />';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
<p id="p2"></p>
<div id="song1"></div>
```

This will be effectively cross-browser, but may request a plugin installation for Firefox.

Comment: Now I have the code thank you, but I keep getting an error "Uncaught type error: cannot set src to null"

Comment: Does it happen for all songs or just a few cases?

Comment: Here [link](http://zachrip.tk/getsongs.php) use chrome, inspect element, and look at the php file. It will show errors when clicking the link.

Comment: Oh, you're using the `audio` tag. Give me a minute to rewrite the code.

Comment: The HTML5 `<audio>` tag only works with Chrome after my testings. You could try the `<embed>` for more compatibility or another method, take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Comment: I know it does, I'm going to have something else for other browsers, I just want this to work

Comment: Then I don't know man, both of the code samples which I posted above (js + php + html) are working perfectly fine on my end.

Answer (score 1):

you have an issue with your quotes. Single quotes do not parse variables. Also, you have some quotes in the wrong place.

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
if ($handle = opendir('/wamp/www/songs/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
          echo "function $entry(){mySong.src='$entry';mySong.play();document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML='Now Playing: $entry';}";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

but you will have another issue with this...your songs probably aren't going to conform to proper function names...you're going to have to rethink this "function for each song" thing...

Comment: Are you sure that `justin bieber - baby.mp3` is a good name for JavaScript function? :)

Comment: well no, but that's a different issue, he'll find out soon enough :P

Comment: Well I'm open for other suggestions on this guys!