# Embed mp3 file into html that works across browsers

Tags: cross-browser, mp3

I am using the following code to embed an mp3 file into my html document:

```
 <embed src="aharddaysnight.mp3" width="140" height="40" autostart="false" loop="FALSE"></embed>
```

In IE, this works fine, as an mp3 player with controls automatically shows up.

In FireFox, however, a pop-up appears that says additional plug-ins are needed. When I click on the option to install additional plug-in, it doesn't allow me to because of a security certificate error.

In Chrome, the player shows up, but the media starts playing automatically, even though the code says autostart "false".

Does anyone have a better way to embed mp3, or a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox and works in both, with the fall back.  However if it is a long file, like the 2 hour audio I am trying it stops playing.  Hopefully it will help you and I will keep looking for my fix.

```
<audio controls="controls">
 <source src="yourURL.mp3" />
 <source src="yourURL.ogg" />
 <!-- fallback -->
  <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"                                                         
    flashvars="audioUrl=yourURL.mp3"    
     src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf"   
     width="650? height="0? quality="best"></embed>
</audio>`
```

Comment: Google reader is no longer supported. This method will not work.

Comment: This method works! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio) is why. If the fallback is really needed you could still load it from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
type="audio/mpeg"
```

OR

```
type="audio/midi"
```