# mp3 songs dont play in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, mp3

I have been struggling for several hours about this.
 http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/releases.html

I am working on this project for a musician and the mp3 songs dont play in Firefox. Chrome, even IE plays them.

Do you know why? Doesn't it support mp3 files? In the documentation of the script it says that you should also have .wav sounds of each file but I have around 25 songs and if I also upload the .wav sounds it would be **too heavy.**

Is there a golden solution? Can I do something so that the mp3 songs play in Firefox? Thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Firefox support mp3 file format in <audio>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support MP3 because it is a patent encumbered codec.  For Firefox you need to re-encode to OGG or WEBM.

Comment: Thanx for your answer..are OGG audio files heavier than mp3?

Comment: @a.litis Depends on the nature of the audio file and the bitrate used.

Comment: @bluewhile Only [when the operating system provides an MP3 decoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP3)