# FF can play mp3, but not using the javascript Audio API

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, mp3

I have this javascript audio player which plays mp3 files. On FF v23.0.1 (Mac) it doesn't work (the reason for this is explained [everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201661/mp3-songs-dont-play-in-firefox) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp))
What I don't understand is, if I point the URL directly to the mp3 file FF shows its own player and the song plays just fine. But when using the javascript Audio API

```
var audio = new Audio('/my-song.mp3') ; // --> HTTP “Content-Type” van “audio/mpeg” not supported
audio.autoplay = true ;
```

it doesn't work. Can someone explain to me why this is ?

Thnx

Comment: Post some code, or it didn't happen. Please note that you must a) use the correct MIME type and b) must either obey same origin or implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: the code above gives me the error in FF. The source file and mp3 come from the same domain (localhost). The response header states that the Content-Type is 'audio/mpeg'. I think thats correct

Comment: And you actually start playing by setting the `autoplay` attribute and/or calling `.play()` on receiving a `canplay` event? Also what does "gives me the error" mean? What's the error message?

Comment: PS: `new Audio()` will actually just creates a `HTMLAudioElement` aka. `<audio>`. You can use it as any other DOM element.

Comment: I've used autoplay (I've updated the question!). I have to add that the player works in Chrome/Safari and IE10. The error is (note that I've translated it to english): HTTP “Content-Type” of “audio/mpeg” is not supported. Loading the media source http://localhost/~me/data/my-audio.mp3 failed.

Comment: There you have it, then. You build does not actually seem to support MP3 yet ;) The player that is shown when directly browsing the .mp3 might be just some plugin handling the Content-Type, such as QuickTime, VLC, etc... That won't fly when using this in an `<audio>` element, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error is (note that I've translated it to english): HTTP “Content-Type” of “audio/mpeg” is not supported.

Your Firefox build does not seem to support MP3 yet.

The player that is shown when directly browsing the `.mp3` might be just some plugin handling the Content-Type, such as QuickTime, VLC, etc... That won't fly when using that file in an `<audio>` element, though.

See the ["Media formats supported..."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) article for information on what codecs are supported by what version of Firefox on what platform.