# HTML5 <audio> element not showing up in Firefox on Mac

Tags: html, html5-audio

http://fowlertown.com/projects/terry/widgets/audio.html

Or if you don't want to click the link, here is the code that matters:

```
<audio type="audio/mpeg; codecs='mp3'" controls src="sample.mp3">Your browser does not support the HTML5 &lt;audio&gt; element.</audio>
```

This isn't showing up in Firefox 15.0.1 and 16.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.4 which depresses me because this is crazy simple HTML5 code. It pops up for a fleeting moment on load but then disappears. It doesn't even show the fallback text.

Thoughts? Is it working for Windows users?

**edit**: http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/ is where I got my browser support list, which indicates FF has supported the audio element (MP3 codec) since version 3.6.

Comment: Working fine in windows!

Comment: it is working in IE 9 but I really don't know what is problem with FF

Comment: I think it has to do with Firefox not supporting mp3 files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio

Comment: Updated original question with my source that says FF supports MP3 since v3.6

Comment: @MJQ What browser+version did you try?

Comment: danfo, that article does not say that FF supports MP3, it says that it suppors Ogg and WAV since 3.6. Firefox does not support MP3 and never did nor is it ever likely to.

Comment: @IanDevlin Yeah, looking now I realize that - I guess i'm cross-eyed and saw the MP3 support for Safari. Whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this tag differently as in firefox you can't play MP3 files with such a code.
Here is the link for your help. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/758978

Firefox doesn't support mp3. See this http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=231069

Comment: Here is another related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio

Comment: Thanks - I guess the article I read was just wrong. Per the idea that FF still doesn't support MP3, I went out seeking an OGG converter. Code only gets slightly more complex, and now I have to maintain two files, but whatever... it works. Thanks.