# Getting audio to play in mobile safari?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

It sure seems unreasonably difficult to get audio to play in mobile Safari on my iPad. Clearly I'm messing up somewhere. I read that you have to have a play action, which I've done, yet it doesn't play the audio. I just want to click an image button and play an mp3. What I've built works fine on my desktop, just doesn't play in mobile Safari.

```
$(".playback").click(function() {
    var selectedAudio = $(this).attr("id");
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(selectedAudio + "-audio");
    myAudio.play();
});​
```

Here's a  fiddle I used for testing. Many thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Pzsax/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick info, your fiddle isn't working in Firefox 17.

Firebug throws:

> The specified "type" attribute of "audio / mpeg" is not supported. Loading the media resource has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the type of audio to "audio/ogg" it stated to work in Firefox. Try the same in Safari. Also you could try adding a secondary source of audio in a different format "audio/mpeg" .mpeg files.

Comment: Sorry about that! My original audio file has to be mp3. Here's an updated fiddle with a new mp3 link for testing. http://jsfiddle.net/Pzsax/5/

Comment: The code in your fiddle works fine for me in safari 5.1.7. However firefox is coming back with "Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.largesound.com/ashborytour/sound/AshboryBYU.mp3 failed." type error again.

Comment: Please read the following post about firefox and audio element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio

Comment: you could also add a fallback option as described here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/

Comment: It works fine for me on Safari on my computer. It's when I try to play it on an iPhone or iPad that it screws the pooch.

Comment: All, my apologies. The code did work as expected in mobile Safari. Thanks for everybody's assistance.