# Playing mp3 file within a specific webpage using javascript/mozilla

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t Firefox support mp3 file format in <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

I am trying to embed a single mp3 file and not a playlist into a site using a Mozilla Add-on. My goal is for this file to play when ever a user visits a specific page, and not the entire site in general. I have chosen that websites Sitemap for an example. My main file is overlay.js, and I don't have any html based files, so I was wondering how would I make this possible, because I have searched the Q/A here, but majority of them explains how to use Audio for Html 5, rather then having a file play in javascript, or when ever a user clicks the Sitemap button. I have tried:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "chrome://path/to/file.mp3";
audio.play();
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support mp3 files. For more information try this: http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/

Comment: Wish I could accept all answers, thanks everyone solution solved.