# Circle player cannot play mp3 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t Firefox support mp3 file format in <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

I am using circle player..to play an mp3 file in a webpage.
It is playing in IE and Chrome but working in Firefox.
Any solution?
Thanks
Here is my Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){                            
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    mp3: "11.mp3"

}, {
cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
canplay: function() {
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
},
supplied: "mp3",
swfPath: "js"
})  

});
```

Comment: [Firefox doesn't support MP3 playback through HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) because of copyright issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help you. But here's my suggestion:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
<div class="jp-type-single">
  <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface all_rounded_corners">
    <ul class="jp-controls">
      <li><a href="#" class="jp-play pp" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause pp" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="jp-previous traverse" tabindex="1">Previous</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="jp-progress" style="display:none;">
      <div class="jp-seek-bar">
        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the correct JS:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
ready: function () {
  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "your-file.mp3" } );
},
swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
supplied: "mp3",
volume: 1,
wmode:"window",
solution: "html,flash",
});
```