# Receiving Stream from soundcloud in different file formats

Tags: javascript, audio, soundcloud

At the moment I am using url to generate `src=""` for an audio tag which looks like:

```
<audio src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/81827374/stream?client_id=my_id" controls>
</audio>
```

However it seem's that such file format (mp3) is not supported in firefox and opera browsers, therefore I need to provide alternative formats, which I assume would look like:

```
<audio preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="some link for .wav file" />
    <source src="some link for .mp3 file" />
    <source src="some link for .ogg file" />
</audio>
```

Is this achievable via soundcloud api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't offer encodings other than MP3 at the moment.

In order to play audio in browsers that don't support MP3 ([Firefox will probably get this support some time soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203792/236135)) you'd need to use a library such as [Audio5JS](http://zohararad.github.com/audio5js/) or [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Comment: When using Audio5JS, how can I acquire mp3 swf fallback file with soundcloud api? (I'm assuming it should be available as soundcloud offers flash fallback for non HTML5 browsers)

Comment: Audio5js should automatically use Flash when mp3 can't be played. Here's an example on how to use SC JS SDK with Audio5JS – http://jsbin.com/ogaqus/4/edit

Comment: The Audio5JS was fixed to follow the redirects without a problem.