# Cant play an Mp3 file in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just created html program to play an Mp3 file using javascript. Its working fine if the program runs from a google chrome, but it wont works with firefox(version24, OS:ubuntu). And it outputs some error in console like `"HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost/phpsound/sound_file.mp3 failed"`. Do I need to install any plugin for firefox to solve this issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="audio/mpeg">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function play_sound()
{
 var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound_file.mp3');
        audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
        audioElement.load();
        audioElement.play();
}
</script>

<body>
<input  type="button"  name="btnOk" id="btnOk" value=" OK " onClick="play_sound();"/>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox can't play `mp3`, but can play files  in `ogg` format.

So you just need to provide an additional `ogg` file and it should work.

---

If you are wondering why, see this question: [Why doesn't Firefox support the MP3 file format in <audio>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

Comment: From the MDN documentation: "The MP3 audio format (.mp3, audio/mpeg; distinct from the above MP3 audio in an MP4 container case) is supported in <audio> by Firefox when the operating system provides an MP3 decoder and by Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: This information is outdated, see this post and references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio/12203792#12203792

Comment: I just changed the file format .mp3 to .ogg, but it output another error in console like HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/plain" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost/phpsound/sound_file.ogg failed.

Answer (score 0):

Audio element() does not support .mp3 file format in Firefox, It only supports .WAV and .ogg file formats.